# Running android project on device from eclim

Tags: android, vim, eclim

I want to use ECLIM plugin for VIM during android development.

The main problem : I can't run my project from eclim, so I can't see logs and errors.

I know such command :

```
  :Ant debug install
```

This command compiles and updates my project to connected device. I have to run it manually. 
I'm not lazy, and is not problem to run it.

But I wish to see runtime's Logs.:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

open a terminal,and input **adb logcat**，then you can see the log.
have a try :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see it exclusively within vim then `:!adb logcat` will display the logs.

Answer (score 0):

Use this in vim:

```
:!ant debug install && adb shell am start -n your.package.name/.YourActivityName
```

That will fire up the app in your device. For logging I just want to complement that if you log in your app use a tag and filter the log by a tag like so: `adb logcat -s "tagname"`